# How to add Multiple Custom Excerpt Lengths In WordPress

Tags: wordpress

By default WordPress excerpts are set to 55 words.I want to get multiple excerpts,each returning different numerical values so I can get short excerpts for blog templates, custom words excerpts for other post type loop. How to do that in wordpress??

Answer (score 4):

you can change content length by using below function

```
// for get_the_excerpt()
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 40, '...' );

// for get_the_content()
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );
```

more info here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/